# Comandos as.Date e srtptime no R

Tags: r, data, time

Suponha o seguinte vetor:

```
datas=c("26/12/2014", "27/12/2014", "28/12/2014", "29/12/2014", "30/12/2014", "31/12/2014")
```

Ao aplicar os comandos `as.Date(datas, "%d/%m%y")` e `strptimes(datas, "%d/%m%y")` a saída é:

```
"2020-12-26" "2020-12-27" "2020-12-28" "2020-12-29" "2020-12-30" "2020-12-31"
```

Por que o Ano (y) está errado? Como ajusto isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar o comando:

```
as.Date(datas, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Note o `%Y` em maiúsculas. Ele indica que o ano está em quatro dígitos.
Qurando você usa o `%y` minúsculo, ele entende que o ano tem apenas dois dígitos e por isso coloca 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Você dever usar o Y maiúsculo, para indicar que o formato do ano tem 4 dígitos.

```
datas=c("26/12/2014", "27/12/2014", "28/12/2014", "29/12/2014", "30/12/2014", "31/12/2014")

as.Date(datas, "%d/%m/%Y") 
#[1] "2014-12-26" "2014-12-27" "2014-12-28" 
#[4] "2014-12-29" "2014-12-30" "2014-12-31"

strptime(datas, "%d/%m/%Y") 
#[1] "2014-12-26 BRST" "2014-12-27 BRST" "2014-12-28 BRST" 
#[4] "2014-12-29 BRST" "2014-12-30 BRST" "2014-12-31 BRST"
```

Comment: Entendido. Quando utilizar o strptime o que significa o "BRST"?

Comment: BRST – Brasília Summer Time (Time Zone Abbreviation)

Answer (score 2):

A função `dmy` do `lubridate` consegue *interpretar* as datas considerando que vêem como (dia, mês, ano):

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(datas)
# [1] "2014-12-26 UTC" "2014-12-27 UTC" "2014-12-28 UTC" "2014-12-29 UTC" "2014-12-30 UTC"
# [6] "2014-12-31 UTC"
```

o mesmo vale para `ymd` e outras variações.